# ActiveMQ Web Console (Jetty) Authentication using LDAP

Tags: authentication, ldap, jetty, activemq-classic

I was wondering if anyone knows how to setup authentication using LDAP for ActiveMQ 5.4.2 Web Console?

It's really simple just to enable basic authentication from jetty.xml and set a new user/pass in clear text in jetty-realm.properties file, but I have many users in LDAP that need to access the web console.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Nerses

Answer (score 1):

You could use JAAS and the LdapLoginModule.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/JAAS

and LdapLoginModule

-jim